# Linux translate blocks of text to lines of text

Tags: linux, bash, text, awk

I have a file that looks like:

```
ignoretext
START
a b
c d
e
END
ignoretext
START
f g h
i
END
ignoretext
```

I want to translate that into rows of:

```
a b c d e
f g h i
```

Comment: Good plan. What have you tried?

Comment: hideous bash while loops with read LINE, and read around on awk, but couldn't figure out how to ignore the start/end lines, and merging them into one line threw me even further off base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '/END/ {ORS=RS;print "";f=0} f; /START/ {ORS=" ";f=1}' file
a b c d e
f g h i
```

---

Added a version that does not give space at the end of line. It may be shorter way to do this

```
awk 'a && !/END/ {printf FS} /END/ {print "";f=a=0} f {printf "%s",$0;a++}  /START/ {f=1}'
a b c d e
f g h i
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I had tried awk '/START/,/END/' as suggested in numerous other posts, but it never succeeded. It'll take me a while just to dissect and understand this.

Comment: The only problems with this solution are it'll add a space to the end of each line and if it ever encountered an END with no START, it'd print a blank line instead of ignoring it. @DavidParks using /START/,/END/ is almost always the wrong approach as it makes the tirival things slightly briefer but then requires a complete re-write or hideous code duplication, etc. for anything even the slightest bit more complicated.

Comment: @EdMorton I did not see the blanks :). Added another version just for fun that does not get the spaces.

Comment: Yeah, every time I do one of these I add a `|tr ' ' '#'` when testing just to make sure as they are hard to spot and sometimes it's not obvious when you're adding them by mistake.

Comment: Ohh, never do `printf $0` or you'll get a nasty surprise when the input data contains a printf formatting char, e.g. `%`. Always use the full printf synopsis of `printf fmt,data` (e.g. `printf "%s",$0`) for printing input data.

Comment: It's a hack, but if you don't care about preserving the details of internal whitespace, you can always pipe the whole thing through another `awk` to remove the surrounding blanks: `| awk '$1=$1'`  It's a useful command to have in your toolbelt anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another variant using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n '/START/,/END/{:a;/START/d;/END/!{N;ba};s/\n/ /g;s/ END//;p}' file
a b c d e
f g h i
```

In a more readable format with explaination:

```
sed -n '                  # Suppress default printing
/START/,/END/ {           # For the range between /START/ and /END/
    :a;                   # Create a label a
    /START/d              # If the line contains START, delete it
    /END/! {              # Until a line with END is seen
        N                 # Append the next line to pattern space
        ba                # Branch back to label a to repeat
    }
    s/\n/ /g              # Remove all new lines
    s/ END//              # Remove the END tag
    p                     # Print the pattern space
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Jotne's `awk` solution is probably the cleanest, but here's one way you can do it with GNU's version of `sed`:

```
sed -ne '/START/,/END/{/\(START\|END\)/!H}' \
     -e '/END/{s/.*//;x;s/\n/ /g;s/^ *\| *$//\p}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'f{ if (/END/) {print rec; rec=sep=""; f=0} else {rec = rec sep $0; sep=" "} } /START/{f=1}' file
a b c d e
f g h i
```